# How to get specific information from this site?

Tags: java, android

I would like to get the information under most shorted stocks such as Symbol, Current Short Int, Previous Short Int, Short In, and Short Share Value. How do i do this, So far i managed to retrieve some information from the site, but this is not what i am looking for, can someone assist me with this.

https://www.benzinga.com/short-interest/most-shorted

```
public class doIT extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String words;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.benzinga.com/short-interest/most-shorted").get();
            words = document.text();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Log.i("words",words);
    }
}
```

Comment: Find an actual API to provide the info, rather than parsing a webpage.  Not only is that generally against the terms of service, but its fragile.  Any change to the html of the page will break your parser.

Comment: Can't afford the api for that information, still in college some sites allow this

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning to display the website on the App you can consider using the [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) object.

But I sense you might want to parse the data and then display it to the view. In that case, you can consider getting the data from a source that can return JSON or XML data for example [Marketstack](https://marketstack.com/)

**Parsing JSON**

I have tried to demonstrate how one can parse JSON using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) on my [Github](https://github.com/brianosoro/Java-Android-Concepts) however you can get better sources online on how to do the same.

I hope this helps.

Comment: On this site we prefer that enough information be added to the answer to understand it without going through a link.  Links become inaccurate or deleted over time, making link only answers lose all their value.